# ZeroMQ (NetMQ) Dealer / Router Socket scalability issue

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, zeromq, netmq

#### Environment

```
NetMQ Version:    4.0.0.239-pre
Operating System:  Linux / Windows
.NET Version:     NET Core 2.1
```

#### Expected behaviour

Hi
I have a multi-client / single server scenario which I am modelling around Dealer / Router sockets. 
I am trying to connect 1000 clients to the server, but the server is able to accept the first 250-350.

#### Actual behaviour

The server is accepting 250-350 connection max.

#### Steps to reproduce the behaviour

Code for the client

#### NetMQClient.cs

```
    public class NetMQClient
    {
        DealerSocket client = new DealerSocket("tcp://127.0.0.1:25702");
        NetMQQueue<NetMQMessage> messageQueue = new NetMQQueue<NetMQMessage>();
        public NetMQClient ()
        {
            messageQueue.ReceiveReady += MessageQueue_ReceiveReady;
            client.Options.Backlog = 1000;
            client.ReceiveReady += Client_ReceiveReady;
        }

        private void Client_ReceiveReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
        {
            while (e.Socket.TryReceiveFrameString(out string msg))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("REPLY From Server{0}", msg);
            }

        }

        public void StartSending(int id)
        {
            client.Options.Identity = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(id.ToString());
            var message = string.Format("Id = {0}", id.ToString());
            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);


            using (var poller = new NetMQPoller())
            {
                poller.Add(client);
                poller.Add(messageQueue);
                poller.RunAsync();

                var messageToServer = new NetMQMessage();
                messageToServer.Append(message);
                messageQueue.Enqueue(messageToServer);
            }
        }

        private void MessageQueue_ReceiveReady(object sender, NetMQQueueEventArgs<NetMQMessage> e)
        {
            while (e.Queue.TryDequeue(out NetMQMessage messageToServer, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)))
            {
                client.SendMultipartMessage(messageToServer);
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Program.cs

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
                {
                    var index = i;
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new NetMQClient().StartSending(index));
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Code for the server

#### NetMQServer.cs

```
    public class NetMQServer
    {
        static RouterSocket server;
        public void StartListening()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started and listening");
            server = new RouterSocket("@tcp://127.0.0.1:25702");
            server.Options.Backlog = 1000;
            server.ReceiveReady += Server_ReceiveReady;

            using (var poller = new NetMQPoller())
            {
                poller.Add(server);
                poller.RunAsync();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private void Server_ReceiveReady(object sender, NetMQSocketEventArgs e)
        {
            var fromClientMessage = new NetMQMessage();
            while (server.TryReceiveMultipartMessage(ref fromClientMessage))
            {
                var clientAddress = fromClientMessage[0];
                var clientOriginalMessage = fromClientMessage[1].ConvertToString();
                Console.WriteLine("From Client: {0}", clientOriginalMessage);

                var messageToClient = new NetMQMessage();
                messageToClient.Append(clientAddress);
                messageToClient.Append(clientOriginalMessage);
                e.Socket.SendMultipartMessage(messageToClient);
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Program.cs

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = new NetMQServer();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => server.StartListening());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to achieve this or is anything wrong with the code above ?
Thank you for your input.

The question has also been posted as an issue on the NetMQ project github repository (https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/issues/832)